# Use the original BRISK implementation

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I want to use the original implementation of BRISK from the authors, since I had some issues with the implementation in OpenCV (you may see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657711/performance-issues-using-brisk-detector-descriptor-opencv)).

Now, I downloaded the library from the [official website](http://www.asl.ethz.ch/people/lestefan/personal/BRISK). In Visual Studio 2012, I added the include path to the header files and the static lib files. When adding #include  to my code, a lot of compiler errors are showing.

Since I use a version of OpenCV 3, some of the errors are caused by the changes between OpenCV 2 and 3 (CvPoint vs cv::Point, uint8_t vs CV_8UC1, etc.). On the other hand, there are errors about missing "agast/oast9_16.h" source files.

I haven't done anything else, so maybe I miss obvious steps...

Comment: False: I can #include <stdint.h> to get around the uint8_t problem

Comment: Screw me again: In the official package, there is a "thirdparty" section with the relevant lib for agast, etc.